# Mathematical definition of a relational database

Tags: relations

I'm reading a very verbose textbook on database design, but I suspect that much of the book could be condensed into a few pages if the authors were not trying to avoid mathematical language.

What is the mathematical definition of a relational database? Stated in a way that a pure mathematician would be satisfied with.

Comment: Relations. Literally that's it. http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Relation

Comment: @AlecTeal: The Wiki page is a handy way of getting the OP to some classic references like the books by Date and Codd. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @AlecTeal I think a relational database is something more than just a relation, so what do you mean? Perhaps a "table" is just a relation, but shouldn't a precise definition of "relational database" express the idea that a relational database is a collection of tables with certain properties?

Comment: @littleO no. Formally they are simply relations. Concepts like "order by" are bolted on afterwards. As are things like properties and foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

I will take your question as a reference request. Your first stop can be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model and the books by Codd and Date cited there.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the earlier answer, from the preface of the book [The relational model for database management: version 2](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=77708&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=712892570&CFTOKEN=13805352) by Codd:

> The relational model is solidly based on two parts of mathematics: first-order predicate logic and the theory of relations.

For more on first-order predicate logic and the theory of relations, I refer you to the following links:

> [First-order predicate logic](http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~saroj/LFP/LFP_2013/L4.pdf)

and

> [Theory of relations](http://fitelson.org/topics/roberts_ch1.pdf)

Edit:  Let me try, as per the OP's request, to define a *relational database* in a few sentences.

> A relational database is a collection of tables, which mathematically are called *relations*.  Each table consists of columns and rows, which are represented in tabular format as follows:

Say your relation is $R = \{(0,0), (0,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4)\}$.  In tabular format, you can have it as:

[image: Relational database illustration]

Comment: Thank you. These references are helpful, but is it possible to simply state a precise definition of a relational database in a few lines?

Comment: @littleO, please check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I come to this from a different angle... I am teaching relations, ostensibly from an abstract perspective, to computer science students... however I want to try and relate what I am teaching to computers in some way.

This is what I do with relations. It is sound on the relations side of the house... databases... I am not so sure.

Let us start with two variables:

- person, $p$, which takes values in $P$, the set of people,
- age, $a$, which takes values in $\mathbb{N}_0$.

We can form the Cartesian product $P\times\mathbb{N}_0$ of $P$ and $\mathbb{N}_0$. This is an infinite set, formed of *ALL ordered pairs* $(p,a)$, where $p$ is a person, and $a$ is a natural number:

$$P\times\mathbb{N}_0=\{(p,a)\,\colon\,p\in P,\,a\in\mathbb{N}_0\}.$$

A *relation* $R$ between $P$ and $\mathbb{N}_0$ is a *subset*, $R\subset (P\times \mathbb{N}_0)$, that is a relation is *SOME ordered pairs*. And this is a database. For example, suppose the relation is:

$$R=\{(\text{Alice},34),(\text{Bob},38),(\text{Carol},33)\}.$$

As a database this would look like:

| person | age |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 34 |
| Bob | 38 |
| Carol | 33 |

Now what we can do is extend the notion of relation to multiple sets. Let us consider two more variables:

- nationality, which takes values in a set $N$,
- country of residence, which takes values in a set $C$.

We can consider the full Cartesian product:

$$P\times \mathbb{N}_0\times N\times C.$$

A relation between these sets is a subset of this, e.g.

$$R=\{(\text{Alice},34,\text{American},\text{Canada}),(\text{Bob},38,\text{Irish},\text{USA}),(\text{Carol},33,\text{English},\text{England})\}.$$

This is a database:

| person | age | nationality | residence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 34 | American | Canada |
| Bob | 38 | Irish | USA |
| Carol | 33 | English | England |

Perhaps a lot of relations do not give databases that arise. For example, the following is also a relation on $P\times \mathbb{N}_0\times N\times C$:

$$S=\{(\text{Alice},34,\text{American},\text{Canada}),(\text{Alice},38,\text{Irish},\text{USA}),(\text{Carol},33,\text{English},\text{England})\}.$$

But is it correctly a database?

I think the databases we have here are more like *partial functions*:

$$P\to(\mathbb{N}_0\times N\times C),$$

so no person appears twice in the database.

I think for databases, there is an implied extra variable. For example, consider the following relation on $\{a,b\}\times \{a,b\}\times\{a,b\}$ (think of these as values of variables $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$:

$$(a,a,b),\,(a,a,a),\,(b,a,b).$$

The database looks like:

| $v_1$ | $v_2$ | $v_3$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $a$ | $a$ | $b$ |
| $a$ | $a$ | $a$ |
| $b$ | $a$ | $b$ |

I would argue that the rows give a natural fourth variable, the row number, $r\in\mathbb{N}$ and so we have a partial function:

$$\mathbb{N}\to (\{a,b\}\times \{a,b\}\times \{a,b\}):$$

| $r$ | $v_1$ | $v_2$ | $v_3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $a$ | $a$ | $b$ |
| 2 | $a$ | $a$ | $a$ |
| 3 | $b$ | $a$ | $b$ |